# Solve the recurrence: $T(n) = \sqrt{2n}T(\sqrt{2n})+\sqrt{n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I found a recurrence of a similar form on this forum, but I couldn't use it to gain any intuition for my question. So far, I've tried 3 things. I've tried unrolling it but could not really see a pattern. I've tried transforming it in hopes that I would be able to use Master's Theorem, but no such luck. I've also tried to guess a complexity and apply induction to see if I can simplify it but I haven't been able to reach a tight bound.

EDIT: Assume that $T(n)$ is constant for $n \leqslant 3$

Comment: That does not make any sense to me. What are the starting values? If one chooses n=1 we have $T(1)=\sqrt 2 T(\sqrt 2 ) +1$. Again $T(\sqrt 2 )$  that does not make any sense. Why do you want to solve this?. What is the source of your problem?

Comment: @miracle173 This is a problem relating to cs complexity analysis. I have a recursive algorithm that behaves like that. Assume that $T(n)$ is constant for $n\leqslant 3$. As for $T(\sqrt{n})$, I should have elaborated that it should be floored, though I can't imagine the specifics would affect the problem much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the variable change:

$\begin{align*}
  n
    &= 2 \cdot 2^{2^k} \\
  k
    &= \log_2 \left(\log_2 \frac{n}{2}\right) \\
  \sqrt{2 n}
    &= \sqrt{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2^{2^k}} \\
    &= 2 \cdot 2^{2^{k - 1}} \\
  \sqrt{n}
    &= \sqrt{2} \cdot 2^{2^{k - 1}} \\
  t(k)
    &= T(2 \cdot 2^{2^k})
\end{align*}$

We get the nice (?) recurrence:

$\begin{align*}
   t(k)
     &= 2 \cdot 2^{2^{k - 1}} t(k - 1) + \sqrt{2} \cdot 2^{k - 1} \\
\end{align*}$

(it is nice in that it is a linear recurrence of first order thus solvable).

Divide through by $2^k \cdot 2^{2^k}$, simplify,

$\begin{align*}
  \frac{t(k)}{2^k \cdot 2^{2^k}}
    - \frac{t(k - 1)}{2^{k - 1} \cdot 2^{2^{k - 1}}}
     &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^k \cdot 2^{2^{k - 1}}}
\end{align*}$

Sum over $1 \le k \le r$, the left hand side telescopes nicely:

$\begin{align*}
   \frac{t(r)}{2^r \cdot 2^{2^r}}
     - \frac{t(0)}{2^0 \cdot 2^{2^0}}
     &= \sum_{1 \le k \le r} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^k \cdot 2^{2^{k - 1}}} \\
    t(r)
     &= 2^{r - 1} \cdot 2^{2^r} t(0)
          + \sqrt{2} \cdot 2^r \cdot 2^{2^r}
               \cdot \sum_{1 \le k \le r} 2^{-k} \cdot 2^{-2^{k - 1}}
\end{align*}$

We get a (*very crude*) upper bound on the sum by:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{1 \le k \le r} 2^{-k} \cdot 2^{-2^{k - 1}}
    &\le \sum_{1 \le k \le r} 2^{-k} \\
    &<   \sum_{k \ge 1} 2^{-k} \\
    &=   \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}$

This gives the bound:

$\begin{align*}
   t(r)
     &\le 2^{r - 1} \cdot 2^{2^r} t(0)
            + \sqrt{2} \cdot 2^{r - 1} \cdot 2^{2^r}
\end{align*}$

A matching lower bound is given by the sum being larger than 0.

This means (throw in a constant to simplify):

$\begin{align*}
   t(r)
     &= \Theta\left(2^r \cdot 2 \cdot 2^{2^r}\right) \\
   T(n)
     &= \Theta\left(2^{\log_2 \log_2 n} \cdot n\right) \\
     &= \Theta(n \log n)
\end{align*}$

Phew!

Answer (score 0):

Let $n\mapsto2n$, divide both sides by $n$, and $f(n)=T(2n)/n$ to get

$$f(n)=2f(\sqrt n)+\sqrt{\frac2n}$$

Now let $n\mapsto2^n$ and $g(n)=f(2^n)$ to get

$$g(n)=2g(n/2)+\sqrt2\cdot2^{n/2}$$

to which you may apply Master's theorem and work backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Making $m=2n$ we have

$$
T(2m)=2\sqrt{m}T(2\sqrt{m})+\sqrt{2m}
$$

and now making $\mathcal{T}(\cdot) = T(2(\cdot))$ we have

$$
\mathcal{T}(m) = 2\sqrt{m}\mathcal{T}(\sqrt{m})+\sqrt{2m}
$$

and

$$
\mathcal{T}\left(2^{\log_2 m}\right) = 2\sqrt{m}\mathcal{T}\left(2^{\log_2 \sqrt{m}}\right)+\sqrt{2m}
$$

Considering now

$$
\mathbb{T}(\cdot) = \mathcal{T}\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right),\ \ \ z = \log_2 m
$$

we follow with the recurrence

$$
\mathbb{T}(z) = 2\times 2^{\frac z2}\mathbb{T}\left(\frac z2\right)+2^{\frac{z+1}{2}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

with solution

$$
\mathbb{T}(z) = z 2^{z+\frac 12}\left(C_0-\sum_{k=0}^{\log_2 z-1}2^{-2^{k-1}+k}\right)
$$

and now backwards, we can obtain $T(n)$

NOTE

Regarding the recurrence $(1)$ we can follow with the transformation

$$
F(\cdot) = \mathbb{T}\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right),\ \ \ u = \log_2 z
$$

reducing  it to

$$
F(u) = 2\times 2^{\frac {2^u}{2}}F(u-1)+2^{\frac{2^u+1}{2}}
$$

This recurrence easily gives the result for $(1)$